# How to render a stateless functional component from another component

Tags: reactjs, render, stateless

I'm new on React. I wrote a project on which there is a search component. the search works fine ( I checked on `console.log`) but I don't know how to call the stateless function component on which the search results should be shown?

```js
class SearchCard extends Component {
  // qQuery is a variable for query input
  state = { qQuery: "" };
  
  HandleSearch= async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const {data:cards}  = await cardService.getAllCards();
    var searchResults = cards.filter((item) =>
      item.qTopic.includes(this.state.qQuery) || 
      item.qArticle.includes(this.state.qQuery)
    );
    this.setState({ cards : searchResults }); 
    //   console.log('search results ',searchResults, '  cards ',this.state);
    return <CardRender cards={cards}/> 
  }  

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <form className="form" onSubmit={ this.HandleSearch }>
          <div className="input-group md-form form-sm form-1 pl-4 col-12">
```

---

```js
const CardRender = ({cards,favs,onHandleFavs}) => {
  return (         
    <div className="row">
      {cards.length > 0 &&
        cards.map((card) =>
          <Card key={card._id}
            card={card} 
            favs={favs} 
            onHandleFavs={() => onHandleFavs(card._id)}
          />
      }
    </div>
 );
}
     
export default CardRender;
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ga7Z.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the `<CardRender cards={cards}/>` to the element `render` returns (at the place you want it to be) and render it if `state.cards` is not empty.

Something like this

```js
class SearchCard extends Component {
  // qQuery is a variable for query input
  state = { qQuery: "" };
  
  HandleSearch= async (e) => {
    // ...
    this.setState({ cards : searchResults }); 
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        ...
        {cards?.length && <CardRender cards={cards}/>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```